# Google App Engine Python - Cost of Datetime Comparison vs. String Comparison

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

hope I can express myself clearly here, bear with me..

Say I have a retail app that sells t-shirts. Each t-shirt can be in a pre-sale, or in-sale phase.

Each time a user goes to a particular t-shirt-page, I can compare the datetime now versus the datetime of when it goes on sale and determine whether it is pre-sale or in-sale and output the appropriate data/content.

Instead, I can have a "phase" string property on my t-shirt, initially set at "presale". I can then set a task queue to execute when the sale starts, and switch the "phase" property of the t-shirt from "presale" to "in-sale". When a user visits a t-shirt page, I check the string, whether it is "presale" or "insale" and output the appropriate data/content.

My question, is one method preferred over the other? I'd assume that the first method, which is a datetime calculation/comparison, would be less efficient than the 2nd method which is based on string comparison? However, the 2nd method requires the use of task queues which adds overhead/cost?

Comment: Have you timed how long the date comparison takes vs the string comparison? Once you do that you know your additional  cost for a single comparison. Then how many of these comparisons will be performed on a single page ?.  Then you know  your total cost.  Now check how long the whole page takes to generate.  What % of the total page cost is the choice of comparing dates vs strings.  That should tell you if it's worth complicating things by constantly reprocessing your "presale/onsale string" . Also constantly processing coiuld be costly.  Especially if your sale date include hours.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is configuration. It's local, it's just reading a file, and it does not compare anything.

Okay, I'll use a structure I've used a lot on my Django and Flask projects. My folder structure usually look like this:

```
main/
 -app/
   |_ __init__.py
   |_ app.py
 -templates/
 -settings/
   |_ __init__.py
   |_ settings.py
   |_ settings.json
_ main.py
```

My settings.py file is where the variables are. It's value it's huge, but it's implementation is simple.
Let's see a example:

```
#settings.py
import json
path_of_json= "path here"
class Settings:
#Object interface of the settings

    class _Product:
    # Non-public class that implements a object interface for the products

        def __init__(self,name,sale_status):
        # Inicialization
        self.name = name
        self.sale_status = sale_status


    def __init__(self):
    #Handles what happens at initialization
        global path_of_json
        self.dict= self._load_json(path_of_json)  #this dictionary will hold the data we load from the JSON
        self.product1 = self._Product(self.dict['product1_name'],self.dict['product1_sale_status'])
        #Here we use the data that were loaded from the JSON
        self.product2 = self._Product(self.dict['product2_name'],self.dict['product2_sale_status'])
    def _load_json(self):
        #Here you implement the JSON loading
        pass
```

That's our configuration file.

Now to the main app, and how to make this do something

```
#main.py
from settings.settings import Settings

my_settings = Settings()
product1 = { "name":my_settings.product1.name,"sale_status":my_settings.product1.sale_status}
#Here the product was loaded from the settings
#A lot of awesome code here


def render_product_page(product):  #This function receives a dictionary
    render_template("sale_status-insert how your template engine show fields here", product["name"])
```

That's how it's (kinda) done.

Now all that you need to implement is a little daemon that wakes each 24 hours, check the data on the `settings.json` file, and if it's outdated, update it. (This I'll leave for you XD)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks so much. Not sure I quite understand your answer. The sale will start at some datetime in the future. It can be weeks or even months. So every time a user visits the page, I have to check the sale datetime vs. datetime.now() to see if it is "presale" or "insale"

Comment: @JK140 I'll write a full fledged answer in a minute,hope I'll help you. Do you have any questions I should try to answer?

Comment: Thanks! I'm just trying to understand the best way to solve this problem. I don't believe it would be efficient to have to check the datetime comparison/calculation every time a user visits the page.

Comment: @JK140 It really is not efficient.

Comment: Yes, your help would be much appreciated in finding a more efficient method.

Comment: I"m not sure if this method is feasible if I have thousands of entries that I need to check?

Comment: Well,if you have thousands of products,then you will use a database (like MySQL). Dealing with those just changes how you deal with the stored data.